# Showing a label information from form 1 to form 2 in Visual basic 2010

Tags: vb.net

Hi guys I just started using visual basic 2010 and I have a problem. I don't know how to show information from form 1 to form 2
it's just a result of a computation on a label

I'm making a receipt in form 2 and I need the results of form 1 to form 2

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gllRL.png)

Comment: Avoid screenshots of code. Please [edit] your question with the code as text, thanks.

Comment: I strongly recommend that you read all three parts of [this blog post](http://jmcilhinney.blogspot.com/2012/04/managing-data-among-multiple-forms-part.html) of mine.

Answer (score 0):

Any time you want to pass data from one class to another you tend to make it happen via property or a method (a constructor is also a method)

You do this all the time:

```
Dim str = "Hello World"

Dim len = str.Length
```

The string knows it's length. You don't know it's length. You call the Length property. The string passes it's length to you. Now you know it's length

```
Dim sb as New StringBuilder

sb.Append(str)
```

StringBuilder did not know your string. You called Append, passing your string. Now StringBuilder knows your string, and contains "Hello World"

---

A huge proportion of the lines of code you write pass data from one object to another. If you want your form objects to do that you just have to facilitate making it happen and the using the facility

You could make the label a public member of the form

```
Dim r as New ResultForm
r.ResultLabel.Text= "the result"
```

You could make a method and call it

```
Public Sub SetResultLabelText(s as string)
  _resultLabel.Text = s
End Sub
...
Dim r as New ResultForm
r.SetResultLabelText("the result")
```

You could add a parameter to the constructor

```
Public Sub New(res as string)
  InitializeComponent()
  _resultLabel.Text = res
End Sub
...
Dim r as New ResultForm("the result")
```